# アイダホの時間は日本の時間から１６時間前もってあります

Tags: english-to-japanese, time

Is this sentence explaining time difference structured correctly?

> アイダホの時間は日本の時間から１６時間前もってあります。

It's supposed to say that the time in Idaho is 16 hours before the time in Japan. If it's incorrect, try to help me figure it out without telling me exactly how to say it.

Comment: In point of fact, Idaho is 16 hours *behind* Japan time. When it's 9:30 am on January 13th in Japan, it's 5:30pm on January 12th in Idaho.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid to say it's incorrect. 前もって means *beforehand* or *in advance*. This is used when someone does something in preparation for something.

Try using 進んでいる or 遅れている instead.